# selenium java code automation for a page having two ckeditors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

While trying to automate a page containing two ck editors,unable to move from one ck editor to the next ck editor.I use the following code for first ck editor

```
WebElement iframe1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe1);
WebElement web1=driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
web1.sendKeys("for testing");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

but unable to switch to the next ck editor in the same page.The another problem while using this is ,these two ck editor iframe had no id to differentiate one another.

Can anyone please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Please add the html for the editors

Comment: Without html, it is difficult to understand what you are asking for. So please  add some html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but does give driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")) more than one result? If so, you could just use the second element for the 2nd ckeditor.

```
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));       
WebElement iframe1 = iframes.get(0); //1st ckeditor
WebElement iframe2 = iframes.get(1); //2nd
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
WebElement element1 = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
element1.sendKeys("some text here..");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

driver.switchTo().frame(2);
WebElement element2 = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
element2.sendKeys("some text here..");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

driver.switchTo().frame(3);
WebElement element3 = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
element3.sendKeys("some text here..");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and so on..

Comment: how do you know there are 3 iframes ?

Comment: I don't know that there are 3 iframes. Just for understanding I added another one.

Answer (score -2):

You should use javascript to enter the text in the ckedtior.
Eg:
for first instance:
$('textarea:eq(0)').val('test').
for second 
$('textarea:eq(1)').val('test')

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: What this code has to do with the question? the webelement is textarea based on what? and there is no reason to use javascript

Comment: I am just saying you can use javascript to enter the text in the two ckeditor. The above textarea thing is just an example.